# Android Maps V2 Failed to load map

Tags: android

well in my case i tried every little step twice or more but not succeeded to load maps. i followed this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key

N generate my **SHA 1** using 
**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool.exe -v -list -alias androiddebugkey -
keystore "C:\Users\User.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android**

But interested thing is when i use browser key (with refers) in manifest.xml my android app loads maps perfectly this means my library n all that settings are right but when i use android key (with certificate) generated in this way 
**mySHA1 key like this 35:56 ... 45:b6;com.example.googlemaps**

it throws exception

```
Failed to load map: Couldn't contact to google server authentication issues
```

where is the problem i can't figure out. need help pls thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try deleting your keys on google console and recreate them. Follow instruction carefully. First time everybody forgets some step.

Make sure you accessing maps-api-v2-android

if you will strictly follow you will get results

Comment: Javanator need more suggestions, I tried what u told, even i created new project from scratch, but now again stuck in the same problem, when i use android key (with certificate) it throws same exception n without solving this i can't move forward.

Comment: the time i started making a sample of google maps v2 android i also faced the failed to load map thing. I found in the end that i didn't enable andorid map services on google api console. instead i enabled map v2 services. test your things on a real device with latest os for testing sake as map will require a gpu host.

Comment: again do everything from scratch including keys generation and try reading instruction on sample map application exactly as they say.